# Pattern matching involving a sum of wildcards

Tags: replacement, pattern-matching

I am trying to implement the following substitution to an expression in Mathematica:

```
ti den[a-ti] -> -1 + a den[a-ti]
```

where `ti` can be `t1`, `t2`, ..., and `den` is an undefined function. The variable `ti` can also be a sum of `t1`, `t2`, .... The expression is part of a larger expression.

Now, it works when one variable is involved:

```
t1 den[s1 + s2 - t1] /. t_ den[q_ - t_] -> (-1 + q den[q - t])
```

returns

> ```
> -1 + (s1 + s2) den[s1 + s2 - t1]
> ```

However, if `ti` is a sum of multiple terms, e.g. `(t1-t2)`, the replacement breaks down. I've tried to implement a rule with the combination of `ReplaceRepeated`.

```
rule = {t_ den[q_ - t_] :> (-1 + q den[q - t])}
(t1 - t2) den[s1 - s12 + s2 - t1 + t2] //. rule
```

but that doesn't seem to work, because it just returns

> ```
> (t1 - t2) den[s1 - s12 + s2 - t1 + t2]
> ```

My guess is that Mathematica cannot recognize `den[s1 - s12 + s2 - t1 + t2]` as `den[s1 - s12 + s2 - (t1 - t2)]` and that my substitution rule is wrongly formulated.

Does anybody know how to fix this?

Comment: try `Unevaluated[(t1 - t2) den[s1 - s12 + s2 - (t1 - t2)]] /. rule`?

Comment: or `Defer[(t1 - t2) den[s1 - s12 + s2 - (t1 - t2)]] /. rule` or `HoldForm[(t1 - t2) den[s1 - s12 + s2 - (t1 - t2)]] /. rule`?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but that only works under the assumption that Mathematica recognizes den[s1 - s12 + s2 - t1 + t2] as den[s1 - s12 + s2 - (t1 - t2)], for arbitrary combinations of t, but it does not..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As m_goldberg explained above, because of the internal representation of expressions, "(a-b)" and "-(a-b" are not simple matched by "t_" and "-t_".
What you can do, is to put the arithmetic of "-(..)" into a condition.
E.g. Match "(t1-t2)" and "-(t1-t2)" by 2 different symbols and use a condition to ensure  that one is the inverse of the other:

```
rule= rule = p1_ den[q_ + p2_] /; (p1 == -p2) -> (-1 + q den[q - p1]);
```

This works now for any number of terms in (t1-t2+t3..):

```
t1 den[s1 - s12 + s2 - t1] //. rule
(t1 - t2) den[s1 - s12 + s2 - t1 + t2] //. rule
(t1 - t2 + t3) den[s1 - s12 + s2 - t1 + t2 - t3] //. rule
```

Comment: thanks, this works. Could you explain where the syntax `rule=rule=..` comes from or point to a reference about it?

Comment: Please excuse , that is simply a cut and paste typo.wo "rule=" are equivalent to one.

Comment: A related question: I'm trying to implement this for arbitrary powers of den as 
`rule = p1_ den[q_ + p2_]^(p3_) /; (p1 == -p2) -> (-1 + q den[q - p1]) (den[q - p1]^(p3 - 1));`
but this only seems to work for p3 not equal to 1. How could I also make it work for p3=1? @DanielHuber

Comment: Additionally, right now I use a separate rule for `p3=1` and apply both rules as `//.{rule1,rule2}`, where `rule1` works for all `p3` except at 1 and `rule2` works only at `p3=1`, but this feels cumbersome.

Answer (score 1):

This is not an answer. I just want to acquaint you with some difficulties you may not be aware of, and my remarks aren't suited to a comment.

Be aware that the Mathematica evauator sees

```
(t1 - t2) den[s1 - s12 + s2 - t1 + t2]
```

as

```
Times[Plus[t1, Times[-1, t2]], den[Plus[s1, Times[-1, s12], s2, Times[-1, t1], t2]]]`
```

and this internal form is the form your pattern matching code has to deal with. And it is clear that there is nothing in the argument of `den` that is going to match `Plus[t1, Times[-1, t2]]` and this is one of the sources of your troubles.

You can observe the internal form yourself by evaluating:

```
(t1 - t2) den[s1 - s12 + s2 - t1 + t2] // FullForm
```

More trouble arises because your pattern cannot distinguish the $s_i$ from the forms $t_i$. And, indeed, there is no way to make the distinction with Mathematica's symbolic pattern matcher.

Answer (score 1):

To make it work for higher powers of "den" you simply specify a default value of p3 by p3_:1. Here some examples:

```
rule = p1_ den[q_ + p2_]^(p3_ : 1) /; (p1 == -p2) -> (-1 + 
      q den[q - p1]) (den[q - p1]^(p3 - 1));
(t1 - t2 + t3) den[s1 - s12 + s2 - t1 + t2 - t3] /. rule
(t1 - t2 + t3) den[s1 - s12 + s2 - t1 + t2 - t3]^2 /. rule
(t1 - t2 + t3) den[s1 - s12 + s2 - t1 + t2 - t3]^3 /. rule
```

Comment: Question regarding the default value, I'm trying to convert all negative powers of `den[..]` to positive powers of a new function `num[..]`. Inspired by your answer, I tried `rule2 = den[a_]^-(p3_ : 1) -> (num[a])^(p3)`, but this now only seems to work for `p3=1`. For instance `1/den[s1 - t1]^2//.rule2` doesn't work. Again, the terms are part of a larger expression, any suggestions? @DanielHuber

Comment: This should do the trick: e.g.:  den[x]^(-3) /. den[x]^p_ /; (p < 0) :> ma[x]^(-p)